# local knowledge of the territory

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, terminology, business-language

In business language, how could you say: `local knowledge of the territory`?

As in: The company has a deep knowledge of the territory, i.e., logistics, suppliers, clients and people knowledge, etc.

Answer (score 2):

One phrase to consider is **regional expertise**. This suggests knowledge of all of the special aspects of the *region* in question.

An alternative might be **market expertise**. *[Market](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/market)* is often used to refer to a geographic area, although in some fields it may refer to a broad product or service sector.

> 1. a geographic area of demand for commodities or services
> 2. a specified category of potential buyers

Comment: what do you think of `regional market expertise`?

Comment: That suggests geography, product and demographic knowledge. If it   is not too wordy for your material, it sounds fine.

Comment: ok. I also wonder what less wordy expressions there could be